# Can't run my self compiled rsync on android What does Illegal Instruction 132 mean?

Tags: android, android-ndk, rsync

I'm trying to learn by compiling the `rsync` source to port to the phone. I've followed some different threads on compiling using the `ndk`. My `lg g4` has the latest marshmallow update from `Verizon`. Here's a list of things I've learned so far:

1. One cannot have an executables run on the sdcard.
2. `/data/local/tmp` doesn't appear to exist or is not writable if you aren't rooted
3. The '`Terminal`' app does create a writable home directory that I can put the executable into.

Which takes me to here ... I've "successfully" compiled `rsync` on my `linux` laptop. By successfully, I mean I have an executable. I can't tell if the executable is valid or not.

Then I did this:

1. On the phone, I started the terminal app.
2. I typed '`cd`' into the terminal app window which took me to a writable home directory under `/data/user/0/........`
3. I launched an `FTP Server` app on my phone.
4. I copied the `rsync` executable from the `linux` laptop to the phone's `sd card` using `filezilla`
5. In the phone's terminal window I cp'd from the `/sdcard/rsync` to the home dir of the terminal app
6. I `chmodded` the `rsync` to 555
7. I typed: `rsync --help`

That is when I see

> 'Illegal instruction 132'

I have no idea what this means. Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: What does `file rsync` say? (with your new rsync file, obviously)

Comment: rsync: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

Comment: The G4 is 64-bit, so perhaps you should try an ARM64 (a.k.a. AArch64, a.k.a. ARMv8) compiler?